# how to show message from function decorator?

Tags: javascript

I want to display a message with the size of coffee when I call the method to.String

```js
function Coffe(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.cost = function () {
        return 5;
    };
    this.toString = function () {
        return this.name + this.cost() + ' USD '+ this.size;
    }
}
var small = function (size) {
    this.size = size;
    size = "small";
    var cost = coffe.cost();
    coffe.cost = function () {
        return cost - 1;
    }
};
var coffe = new Coffe('Latte ');
small(coffe);
console.log(String(coffe));
```

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.  Are you asking for `.toString()`?

Comment: Are you sure you mean *decorator*? If so, what version of the decorator proposal are you using? This doesn't look like any I've seen.

Comment: yes, when i call  to.string i wan't to see: "latte 5 USD small"

Comment: What is your expectation within the `small()` function in relation to the keyword `this` and the global variable `coffe`? What do you suppose `this` refers to in that function?

Comment: The parameter of your function should not be called `size` if you pass in a `Coffe` instance. You should not use the global `coffe` variable in the function. And you should not use `this` if you're not calling `small` as a method.

Comment: @AndrewBone - learn javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: @RandyCasburn little rude but point taken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little bit of modification and it works.

```js
function Coffe(name) {
    // I would recommend setting some appropriate default value to
    // this.size since every coffee has a size (you might omit this.size 
    // declaration here but then you will not get a pretty toString output
    // without calling small)
    this.size = "";
    this.name = name;
    this.cost = function () {
        return 5;
    };
    this.toString = function () {
        return this.name + this.cost() + ' USD '+ this.size;
    }
}

// pass a coffee instead of size - which was coffee anyway
const small = function(coffe) {
    coffe.size = "small";     // change size of the provided coffee
    let cost = coffe.cost();
    coffe.cost = function () {
        return cost - 1;
    }
};

var coffe = new Coffe('Latte ');
small(coffe);
console.log(String(coffe));
```

Comment: This is still not a _function decorator_

Comment: @RandyCasburn True. It is just modified version of OP's code that works.